Motor with self-latching relay and braking function
I have a DIN 72552 latching relay connected to a 12VDC 775 motor and want to add a braking function. The motor has a stall current of 10A. I found this schematic that implements a braking function for a motor using two Darlington transistors, one NPN and one PNP, to start and brake the motor, respectively:

Source: https://www.edn.com/circuit-forms-dc-motor-switch-with-brake/
Can the same circuit be implemented using MOSFETs instead of Darlingtons?
I've attempted to replicate the above circuit by replacing the NPN and PNP Darlingtons with N-channel and P-channel MOSFETs. I'm using a DIN 72552 latching relay, latched by a single press momentary "start" switch, to turn the N-channel MOSFET on and a normally closed "stop" switch to unlatch the relay and cause the braking function to kick in:

I'm also unsure of what the values ought to be for each of the resistors. I would guess the resistors going to gate (R1 and R3) should be smaller values while the pull-down resistor R2 should be ~10K?

The new arrangement will work, but MOSFET needs a minimum Vgs to be activated (Vth), depends on model, can be higher than Vbe of BJT (a Darlington transistor should need about 2xVbe to work). The voltage drop in Q1 will be about Vcc*R1/(R1+R2) added to Vth. The gate has a high impedance and you are not switching fast, so R2 can have a high value. Q1 is working in linear area, it needs to be checked carefully. Q2 will not brake when motor´s EMF is below Vth, and R3 should be selected so the leakage currents of D1 and Q1 is pulled down safely. A diode in the coil of relay will protect for inductive voltage spike. The only improvement should be lower control current for Q1´s gate.

I tried the circuit above with an IRF4905 MOSFET, which specifies a Vgs threshold mininum at 2V, and the motor braked but once the voltage got below 2V it stopped braking. The TIP125 PNP transistor, however, specifies no minimum Vbe on, but lists a maximum Veb voltage of only 5V. Does this mean the above circuit will most likely damage a TIP125 when it attempts to brake the motor since the motor's EMF will start at 12VDC?

@stibbshoo : datasheet states a absolute max Vbe that will damage the transistor. You will also find Vbe(on) max of about 2.5 V with a define Ic, but the Darlington will be activated (with lower current)  with only 2x0.7 V= 1.4 V. EMF will normally be a little lower than supply, and Ib will be limited by R3, no issue.
